# Convert pandas.timedelta64[ns] to int (preferably nanoseconds)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` with a column `Time`, made of `pandas.timedelta64[ns]` objects and I would like to convert it to integer values (preferably nanoseconds). I have tried using the `.astype("int64"):`

```
df["Time"] = df["Time].astype("int64"),
```

which returns the error: `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Timedelta'`,

```
df["Time"] = df["Time].view("int64"),
```

which returns the error: `Cannot change data-type for object array.`

Can someone point me in the right direction? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can do arithmetic on NumPy `timedelta64` objects, so if the `timedelta` in your column are all of the same scale, you can divide them by whatever factory necessary to convert to nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

NumPy `timedelta` objects allow you to do arithmetic between them, so if all of the values in the 'Time' column are on the same `timedelta` scale, you can just apply a transformation by the appropriate factor to get nanosecond. For example, to go from days to nanoseconds:

```
> import numpy as np
> td1 = np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
> td2 = np.timedelta64(1, 'ns')
> td1 / td2
86400000000000.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @LiamFiddler however, I tried converting my `pandas.timedelta64` objects to `numpy.timedelta` using `to_numpy()` and dividing by a single nanosecond, but it still returns a pandas.timedelta64

Comment: Would you mind including the code for that?

Comment: `df["Time"] = df["Time"].to_numpy() / int(numpy.timedelta64(1,'ns'))`

Comment: Try running just the denominator in your console  / IDE and let me know what you get. I think that'll solve your problem.